# Lifecycle observer weird behavior

Tags: android, androidx, android-lifecycle

I'm using lifecycle observer of the application and I'm listening for `ON_START` like this
`ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(lifecycleObserver)`

```
private val lifecycleObserver = object : LifecycleObserver {
        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
        fun onProcessResume() {
            Log.d("TAG", "ON_START")
        }
    }
```

when I register this observer it triggers immediately even if I added this observer in `onResume` callback.

I expected this to trigger in the next onStart call not immediately. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter where you register your `lifecycleObserver`, because after registration the given observer will be brought to the current state of the `LifecycleOwner`.